# Java copy files from source zip to destination zip on Oracle database

Tags: java, oracle, zip

Have a Word DOCX file stored in a table (zip file). With Java stored procedure, I like to replace some string inside "word/document.xml" file and store all files into new archive. If I run the code on Oracle database I get corrupted zip file. File size of ouptut file is smaller than input file...
If I run the same app on client (Netbeans IDE) then all works fine. I can't find the where is the problem!?

```
 public static void zamenjajVsebino(oracle.sql.BLOB srcBlob1, oracle.sql.BLOB[] dstBlob) throws Exception {

    InputStream zipBuffer = srcBlob1.getBinaryStream();
    OutputStream outBuffer = dstBlob[0].getBinaryOutputStream();

    ZipInputStream zipIn   = new ZipInputStream(zipBuffer);
    ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(outBuffer);
    ZipEntry inEntry;

    while ((inEntry = zipIn.getNextEntry()) != null) {

        ZipEntry outEntry = new ZipEntry(inEntry.getName());
        zipOut.putNextEntry(outEntry);


        if (inEntry.getName().equals("content.xml") | inEntry.getName().equals("word/document.xml")) {
            String contentIn = new String(getStringByte(zipIn), "UTF-8");


            contentIn = contentIn.replaceAll("%TEXT%", "BLA BLA");

            zipOut.write(contentIn.getBytes(), 0, contentIn.getBytes().length);
        } else {
            copy(zipIn, zipOut);
        }

        zipOut.closeEntry();
    }

    zipIn.close();
    zipOut.flush();
    zipOut.finish();

}

 public static void copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {

    int n;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while ((n = in.read(buffer)) > -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, n);   // Don't allow any extra bytes to creep in, final write
    }
    out.flush();
}
```

If I open the source DOCX file is like this:

[image]

The output file is like this:
[image]

Here is my plsql source code:

```
-- select source docx file from blob...
   select vdb.vsebina
   into   SrcBlobLocator
   from   dok_vsebina_dokumenta_blob vdb
   where  id=p_vdb_id;

   -- prepare output blob
   p_vdb_id_out:=dok_lob.f_pripravi_blob;

   update dok_vsebina_dokumenta_blob set 
   naziv_datoteke='test.docx', 
   vsebina = empty_blob()
   where  id=p_vdb_id_out;

   --select output blob for update...
   select vdb.vsebina
   into   DstBlobLocator
   from   dok_vsebina_dokumenta_blob  vdb
   where  id=p_vdb_id_out for update; 


  -- call java stored procedure with source and dest blob... 
  ZamenjajVsebino(SrcBlobLocator, DstBlobLocator);
```

Comment: You must check that you run your program with the same java version.

Comment: Oracle Java stored procedures run on internal Java, that is usually 1.3 or so...

Comment: No.. Java is 1.6 it's oracle 11g... something must be wrong with streams?!

Comment: The problem was dstBlob[0].getBinaryOutputStream(); it must be dstBlob[0].setBinaryStream(1L);